# Why doesn't ArrayDeque override equals() and hashCode()?

Tags: java, collections, equals, hashcode

**EDITED:** Now only ArrayDeque is considered. (I originally thought `LinkedList` also doesn't override the two methods.)

Collection type `ArrayDeque` simply uses the `hashCode` and `equals` method implementations that it inherits from Object.

Why doesn't it instead override these methods with proper implementations (i.e. hash and equality test based on contained elements)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) extends [`AbstractSequentialList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html) which extends [`AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) which *does* override `equals` and `hashCode` - so the implementation is *not* inherited from `Object`.

[`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), on the other hand, really *doesn't* inherit anything other implementation as far as I can see. Its direct superclass ([`AbstractCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html)) doesn't override them. This feels like an exception rather than the rule - I believe *most* collection implementations in Java "do the right thing".

I don't know of the justification for `ArrayDeque` choosing not to implement equality, but if you want to compare two deques you could easily just convert them into lists or arrays and do it that way.

Comment: An exception or even an oversight/bug.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Indeed. We can't really tell which easily :( (The docs don't say as far as I can tell.)

Comment: Clearly a bug. `ArrayDeque` implements `Collection` which defines the `equals()`method for collections. `ArrayDeque` does not adhere to that contract.

Comment: @devconsole: Which precise bit of the contract does it not adhere to? The documentation of `Collection.equals` includes "the Collection interface adds no stipulations to the general contract for the Object.equals" and "It is not necessary to do so (meaning override `equals`), and the simplest course of action is to rely on Object's implementation".

Comment: @JonSkeet: you are right of course, sorry for the oversight.

Comment: Actually the opposite is true, [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) explicitly states that "Deque implementations generally do not define element-based versions of the equals and hashCode methods, but instead inherit the identity-based versions from class Object".

Comment: If you want to implement your own equals and hashCode, a way that is slightly more performant and IMHO more concise than creating lists is to call deque.toArray() and pass the result to java.util.Arrays.hashCode resp. Arrays.equals.

Comment: @Martin: Creating an array copy doesn't sound like it's good for performance to me...

Comment: I wrote "slightly more performant ... than creating lists", as creating lists always involves copying arrays, but also some extra overhead.

Comment: @MartinRust: True. I suspect I replied on a mobile without checking the context enough. Will edit to "lists or arrays".

Answer (score 2):

They are overrided in `AbstractList`, that is present in `LinkedList` inheritance

Comment: For LinkedList, yes they are overriden. But for ArrayDeque, as Jon mentioned, the implementation from Object is used.

Answer (score 2):

It generally does not make sense for object *instances* which are going to be mutated to report themselves as equal to anything other than themselves.  The primary reason that instances of some mutable collection types report themselves as equal to other collection instances that it is common for code to hold references to instances which, even though they "could" be mutated, won't be.  Although code could hold references to two `ArrayDequeue` for the purpose of encapsulating all of the items that have ever been or *are ever going to be* put in them, and it might make sense to compare the contents of two `ArrayDequeue` instances which are held for that purpose, the whole purpose of the type is to facilitate the pushing and popping of items; in cases where it would make sense for `equals` to check for identical content, it would likely also make sense to extract the contents into a type whose purpose is to encapsulate a list.

Comment: just makes it slightly confusing when you write unit test cases and then `assertEquals` fails :)

Answer (score 0):

According to official Javadoc - you're not correct. LinkedList use equals from AbstractList, that perform deep equals

For more information - look at this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

With Guava you can use the `Iterables.elementsEqual` method.